# Cannot install Intel drivers from CD (browser driven install)

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, internet-explorer, drivers

I'm trying to install some Intel drivers in a Windows Server 2008 R2 (64 bits) box. These drivers come in a CD. Problem is, this is a "browser-driven" install. And Internet Explorer, in this server environment, is very quirky when it comes to security.

When I try to select the driver for my Windows version, Internet Explorer says that IE ESC (Enhanced Security) blocked the page and suggests adding it to the trusted sites. When I try to do so, using `file://`, I cannot add it, IE tells me that there invalid wildcard characters in the path.

Here's what I tried:

- Disabling IE ESC temporarily: same results
- Browsing the CD contents with file explorer: Inside the folder IE doesn't let me access, there are many zip files, full of .inf, md5, .sys, .inf files, but no Setup.exe. I extracted everything to a temporary folder and told Windows to look there when seeking drivers. This way, I got rid of all warnings in Device Manager. But the CD contains extra utilities, and the device drivers list in the browser install was way longer than the list of warnings in device manager. So I feel I'm missing things.

I believe the main problem is that the zip files in the paths confuse IE. Any ideas?

**Edit**: The URL IE is blocking is:

```
D:\drivers\sw-raid\ESRT2_Windows_v.14.06.1007.2011.WHQL.zip\2k8r2-x64_v14.06.1007.2011
```

`D` corresponds to my DVD drive. I can access this folder using file explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to download the utilities you need directly from IBM's website.  They have seperate install files for every utility and driver available, for all of their servers.  You don't mention which server you have, so I can't point you to the exact page, but searching on [IBM's support page](http://www.ibm.com/support/us/en/?lnk=msd-0-usen) should bring it up.

In fact, I usually just throw the driver CDs out.  By the time they are manufacturer and delivered, at least one or two of the drivers will have updates available already.  Just get the newest ones from their website.  IBM is quite good about making sure they are all there, and all up to date.

You may not actually need all the drivers on the CD - Server 2008R2 will come with some built in or via windows update that are newer than the ones on the CD.